# errors building glut dll with visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, glut

I have upgraded visual studio from 2010 to 2013. I've downloaded GLUT source code distribution from [here](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html). In the instructions,

```
       To build the glut dll: 
       First, open Microsoft Developer Studio.
       Then, select File -> Open Workspace and find the glut.dsw file
       in the file dialog and double-click on it.  
       Finally, select Build -> Build glut32.dll.
       When the build is finished, it will copy:
       glut32.dll to %WinDir%\System, 
       glut32.lib to $(MSDevDir)\..\..\VC98\lib, and 
       glut.h     to $(MSDevDir)\..\..\VC98\include\GL.
```

There is no folder named `VC98`. `GL` folder is located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\gl
```

As a result, I can't build `glut.dll`. It throws out the following message

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: The command "copy C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\glut-3.7.6\lib\glut\Debug\glut32.dll %WINDIR%\SYSTEM32
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: copy C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\glut-3.7.6\lib\glut\Debug\glut32.lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\..\..\VC98\lib"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(132,5): error MSB3073: copy ..\..\include\GL\glut.h "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\..\..\VC98\include\GL"
```

How can I build glut dll successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those error messages are caused by a [Post-Build Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7dhf0ty.aspx).
You can safely ignore these.
You will find the dlls in `glut-3.7.6\lib\glut\` under `Debug` and `Release`.

Comment: you are right. But when I did link against them, the app crashes and it is telling me `text.exe` has stopped working`. I suspect visual studio 2013 I have no idea what is going on. I've accepted the answer since the dll has been generated but still the app crashes even with simple codes like opening a window.

Comment: @CroCo did you link against the new .lib and replace the .dll?

Comment: yes I did. This is why I don't know the reason behind this crash.

Comment: @CroCo are you using the right platform toolset in your app (in your case **Visual Studio 2013 (v120)**)?

Comment: what do you mean? Is possible that you generate the dll by using visual studio 2013? I would like to see if it is gonna work. I'm thinking to go back to visual studio 2010.

Comment: @CroCo so you did not generate the dll using Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: I did. It is not working. I don't know where is the problem. I'm thinking to install visual studio 2010 and generate the dll to make sure where is the problem. Even SDL2 is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69584/discussion-between-axalo-and-croco).

Comment: It seems that the problem  has nothing to do with visual studio. I'm still unable to fix it. I think I need to post another question regarding this matter.

Comment: that's what I was thinking too.

Comment: It seems something with video card.

Comment: I doubt it. It's probably something with your linking. Could be the wrong .lib. But we had this discussion before...

Comment: I installed visual studio 2010. My old projects won't work any more.

Comment: @CroCo [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69584/discussion-between-axalo-and-croco)

Comment: now it is working. I did format my computer but it seems the problem with the video card driver